# Change pseudo element when another class present

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the `after` pseudo element when the `.active` class is added, but this doesn't seem to be working correctly.

I'm currently using `scss` in my project with Vue. I've already tried the following:

```
li {
    position: relative;
    &::after {
        opacity: 0;
        bottom: -10px;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        width: 0%;
        height: 3px;
        background: $light-blue;
    }
}

// When this class is present, adjust the pseudo element to different width
.active {
  color: $light-blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;

  li::after {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 60%;
  }
}
```

I've also tried the following as well

```
.active {
  color: $light-blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;

  &::after {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 60%;
  }
}
```

What would be the correct way to adjust the pseudo element from the `li` element through another class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SCSS:

```css
li {
    position: relative;
    
    &::after {
        opacity: 0;
        bottom: -10px;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        width: 0%;
        height: 3px;
        background: $light-blue;
    }
    
    &.active {
      color: $light-blue;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      position: relative;
      
      &::after {
        opacity: 1;
        width: 60%;
      }
    }
}
```

Compiled to the following code in CSS:

```css
li {
    position: relative;
}

li::after {
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 0%;
    height: 3px;
    background: $light-blue;
}

li.active {
  color: $light-blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

li.active::after {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 60%;
}
```